# How to add SPAN container in Django CKEDITOR

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

I'm trying to add span container to my ckeditor in my django project,
currently my Ckeditor have just DIV container,
but I need to add SPAN container just like the Div container to able me add some span container.
my django settings has:

```
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'
CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js'
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = 'pillow'
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'awesome_ckeditor': {
        'toolbar': 'full' ,
        'width': '100%',
    },
}
```

Comment: How is this a Python or Django question actually ?

Comment: Its Ckeditor for Django, and Django is based on Python

Comment: What have you tried or researched so far?

Comment: @Arash it's not "Ckeditor for Django", it's eventually "Ckeditor in some reusable django app" or "Ckeditor manually added to a Django project" (you didn't even specify which), and in both cases, the question is basically "how to configure ckeditor to support this feature", and this problem would be the same if you were using PHP, Rails or whatever. Once you solved this, how to translate this into the solution you're using to integrate ckeditor in your project depends on the solution itself (which you did not specify) and is probably quite trivial.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers this package named "django-ckeditor" and its a integrated version which you can find it on github. if you know the solution please keep continue